# Why isn't pure animal fat appetizing to humans?

Tags: evolution, nutrition

When eating beef or lamb, humans almost invariably trim away the gristle. Tastes are a bit more varied with poultry and pork but, there too, most people don't like to eat pure animal fat. (Although bacon is very popular, and some people like to eat pure schmaltz or lard.)

But isn't this strange from an evolutionary sense? The fat is the most calorically dense part of the animal, so shouldn't we have evolved to find it appetizing?

Comment: Have you asked most people why they trim away fat? If they didn't like fat, producers of beef would not feed cattle in a way that produced optimal *marbling*. People would not eat potato chips. French fries would be disgusting. The snack food industry wouldn't be buying millions of tons of palm oi every year. Etc., etc. Your statement isn't founded in science.

Comment: Culture plays a strong part in food and taste preferences - it's not all genetic / evolutionary.

Comment: This question is based on the false premise that what is prevalent in the tastes of where the OP lives universally true. Go to a country where traditionally people don't have enough to eat like Vietnam and they're all about the lumps of fat. I guess you could compare it to a spoonful of crystal sugar. You probably don't find that very appetizing either because it's quite abundant now and it's better when accompanied by other things which you have been accustomed to. But when it is lacking, the pure stuff is going to seem really attractive.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, in my mind. I see your point, humans love sugary sweets, but why not fatty lumps of lard? Well, humans do love fatty lumps of lard! The American diet consists of disproportionately higher amounts of saturated fatty acids. So, people tend to go for and prefer calorically denser foods anyhow. As you mention, people still use lard for cooking incredibly often, so even pure fat is at least appealing.

However, the gristle we refuse to eat isn't really fatty and is mostly inedible depending on the cut of the meat. There is an incredible amount of sugar when you look at a tree, but do you get hungry? I imagine not, because the tree is mostly inedible. So even if the resources are there, they still have to be edible for anyone to want to eat them in the first place.

Comment: Humans love fatty lumps of lard, especially when sugar is added. It's called a cookie.

Comment: I have eaten roasted bone marrow, which is basically a lump of fat. then you have fatback, lardo, ect. we don't like almost anything a pure refined state, but as it exists in the wild eating fat is pretty common.

Answer (score 4):

I've just been reading a novel about the Inuit — [“De pierre et d’os” by Bérengère Cournut](https://le-tripode.net/livre/berengere-cournut/de-pierre-et-dos). The Inuit are (or were) very partial to animal fat — raw of course — and much else besides that 21st century urban man would consider unappetizing. If they weren’t, they wouldn’t have been able to survive.

So before talking about human evolution it is advisable to think on a somewhat longer timescale than that of contemporary US urban civilization, and to recognize temporary cultural fads for what they are.